# Grails Spring Security s2ui-override

Tags: grails, spring-security

Sorry for the stupid question, I'm new to grails. I'm trying to provide Spring Security registration in grails by applying a plugin with command `grails s2ui-override auth` like in the tutorial http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-ui/guide/userRegistration.html, but get

```
 Error Command not found s2ui-override
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: do you have the plugin declared in your build file ?

Comment: gradle cannot compile plugin `compile ":spring-security-ui:1.0-RC2"`

Comment: do you also declare `core` ? and are you using grails 3 ? I am not sure this plugin has been ported, `core` is available for grails 3 on bintray but not `ui`

Comment: yes, I'm using grails 3 and added  `'org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:3.0.0.M1'` and it compiled, but neither `"org.grails.plugins:spring-security-ui:0.2"` nor `"org.grails.plugins:spring-security-ui:1.0-RC2"`doesn't compile

Comment: so thats it, the plugin is not compatible with grails 3. you have 3 solutions: downgrade to grails 2.x; skip the ui plugin and do the implementation yourself; wait for the plugin to be ported (or better do it)

Answer (score 0):

You must configure in build.gradle for grails versions 3.0.x, 3.1.x and 3.2.x

```
compile 'org.grails.plugins:spring-security-ui:3.0.2'
```

look at https://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-ui/latest/